# Class 'dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor' not found

Tags: php, yii2, ckeditor

I am working on a project in `Yii2` where I need to integrate `CKEditor`. I used this to install it:

```
composer require 2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget
```

It downloads the library files under /vendor directory. When I copied the files from local to server and used this:

```
use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;

<?= $form->field($userSurveyConfig,
      'survey_email_body')->widget(CKEditor::className(),
      ['options' => ['rows' => 6],'preset' => 'basic'])
?>
```

When I run the page, this error pops up:

```
> Class 'dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor' not found
```

What i am doing wrong here? Any help?

Comment: Do you run `composer update` on server? From description, u just copied manually /vendor, try to copy `composer.json` and run `composer update` on server.

Comment: I have copied the `composer.json` file but didn't run the command. Let me try that, may be that will solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy `composer.json` file to server and run `composer update` on server.